# Punishment for a man being naked

Tags: punishment, awrah

Assalamualaikum,
I want to know is there any punishment for a man who exposes his awrah (between navel to knee) in front of other people whether it is a man or woman like in changing room or showering area/pools as in western/european regions there is a concept of open changing and all. I know that a man should cover his private parts from non mahram but if he is exposing his body thinking that it's ok I am only naked for few minutes and not committing any zina just standing at a distance from others or naked by thinking other things.
Because once he gets naked for the first time it may become a habit of being naked again later on.

So are there any punishments mentioned in the islamic sources like whether he will be punishable either in grave or after qayamah by Allah. So please tell me about the punishment for a man in particular as for a woman I have read about it but couldn't find anything about a man's punishment.
A man being naked is haraam (forbidden/not permissible) but is it a sin?

I am asking this for information purposes.

Comment: doing anything Haram is a sin.